# How to choose a not in use variable name when creating HTML element?

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on making a sort of chat room where you can talk to a bot that looks for keywords in your message and replies based on that keyword. I am in the stage where I've figured out how to create a new chat element based on what you have messaged but my thought process on doing that is to make a new element with a name with the following code `const Chat = document.createElement("div");` but when you edit that div text with the message text it would change the text for all divs with that name. And when you keep recreating that div with the same name that's what happens. So I have been researching how to randomize a name and the simplest way I thought of was to have all variables start with the word chat and add a number to the end. Like so... `Chat0, Chat1, Chat3` I can't change the variable name with a fixed function to create the element.

If anyone has any suggestions, I'm all ears :)

Comment: you can give divs ids or classes. i'd create a random uuid for each chat message and attach it as an id or class to the div, that way you have an identifier to go based on. idk what java has to offer but with node/javascript I use uuidv4 or nanoid. but i'm confused. are you trying to not have clashing html elements or variabes in code? if you're referring to in-code variables you probably want to use an array instead of 1 off variables. each item in the array can be an object with an identifier. also, are you working with java or javascript?

Comment: @duxfox I suggest you make an Answer of your Comment.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question accurately, and it sounds like you're using javascript (not java), so I'm going with that assumption for my answer:

if you're trying to store each chat message in a separate in-code variable, then that's not going to work. You probably want to store the chat messages in an array, where each item in the array is an object; something like this structure:

```
const chatMessages = [
  { id: 'xyz123', text: 'chat message text' },
  { id: 'abc456', text: 'chat message 2' },
];
```

etc... and as you create more chat messages, you add them to this array. The ids would be uuids generated using a library like
[uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) (you want the uuid/v4 version),
[uuidv4](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuidv4), or
[nanoid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nanoid).

if you want to avoid naming clashes with the `divs`, then you can add an id or class to your divs and inject the ids from above into those attributes, this way you can distinguish between your div elements;

```
<div id={id_from_above}></div>
// or
<div class={id_from_above}</div>
```